# using tikz in multicol

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, multicol

I try to use `tikz` in a `multicols` environment, but it makes me a lot of problems to put in to the right size and to give it a caption.

I try a `\resizebox` to make the picture fit the column, but it does not work properly (the picture overlays the next column).

Also I have no idea how to label the picture. `\caption` is only allowed in a floating object but floating objects are forbidden in `multicols`...

Here is my test-document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\section{My Section}]
        \blindtext

        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \centering 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill (0,0) rectangle (10cm, 5cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \parindent0mm

        \blindtext

        \blindtext
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! is there special reason, that you use `multicol` package. Is not sufficient `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`? For caption in not floating environment you need `caption` or `capt-of` package and than use `\caption{figure}{<caption title>}`.

Comment: There is no special reason why I use [multicol]. I simply don't  know that the twocolumn option exists. This is an excellent solution, couse twocolumn allowed floatin objects, thanks a lot!

Comment: then see, if `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \section{My Section}
\blindtext
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my tikz picture}
    \end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}` gives what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you only need a two column document and not anything else from `multicol`, you can simply start your document with `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}`.
- In standard two column documents you can use floats (figures or tables) as on one column document. Caption in them work as expected

Complete document, derived from yours is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \section{My Section}
\blindtext
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my tikz picture}
    \end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: result]